# Logging with multithreading

Tags: multithreading, logging

I have two threads running at the same time which are picking up items from the same queue and processing them. However, sometimes I get exceptions because they are trying to access the same object, when one has already picked it up. I looked up solutions online and people said to use logs to tell one thread or the other to wait. How does this work? What approach would you take to use logs?

Comment: I think they meant locks, not logs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) link. it describes what a lock is. without knowing the language you are using I cant really be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for adding that. I am coding in Java. I will go ahead and take a look at locks. Thank You.

Comment: @malvarn123 this is a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/